# Implementing a transition via @keyframe

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to implement a transition with a @keyframe animation that changes the background gradient but can't seem to put my finger on where I'm going wrong.

Right now the background just jumps from gradient to gradient with no transition.

Link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8GGW/)

CSS:

```
.box {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:800px;
  background: #071435;
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-44deg, rgba(255, 22, 150, 0.64) 0%, rgba(178, 136, 12, 0.85) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-44deg, rgba(255, 22, 150, 0.64) 0%, rgba(178, 136, 12, 0.85) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-44deg, rgba(255, 22, 150, 0.64) 0%, rgba(178, 136, 12, 0.85) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-134deg, rgba(255, 22, 150, 0.64) 0%, rgba(178, 136, 12, 0.85) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-134deg, #3EAD7E 0%, rgba(29, 83, 60, 0.72) 52%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-134deg, #3EAD7E 0%, rgba(29, 83, 60, 0.72) 52%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-134deg, #3EAD7E 0%, rgba(29, 83, 60, 0.72) 52%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-224deg, #3EAD7E 0%, rgba(29, 83, 60, 0.72) 52%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47) 100%);
  opacity:1;
}

.box:hover {
  -webkit-animation: playbg 3s infinite;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes playbg {
  0% {
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-44deg, rgba(255, 22, 150, 0.64) 0%, rgba(178, 136, 12, 0.85) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-44deg, rgba(255, 22, 150, 0.64) 0%, rgba(178, 136, 12, 0.85) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-44deg, rgba(255, 22, 150, 0.64) 0%, rgba(178, 136, 12, 0.85) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-134deg, rgba(255, 22, 150, 0.64) 0%, rgba(178, 136, 12, 0.85) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-134deg, #3EAD7E 0%, rgba(29, 83, 60, 0.72) 52%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-134deg, #3EAD7E 0%, rgba(29, 83, 60, 0.72) 52%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-134deg, #3EAD7E 0%, rgba(29, 83, 60, 0.72) 52%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-224deg, #3EAD7E 0%, rgba(29, 83, 60, 0.72) 52%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47) 100%);
    opacity:1;
  }
  20% {
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(4, 91, 255, 0.64) 11%, #00FDF2 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(4, 91, 255, 0.64) 11%, #00FDF2 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(4, 91, 255, 0.64) 11%, #00FDF2 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, rgba(4, 91, 255, 0.64) 11%, #00FDF2 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-114deg, #FF1111 29%, rgba(255, 62, 30, 0.50) 97%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-114deg, #FF1111 29%, rgba(255, 62, 30, 0.50) 97%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-114deg, #FF1111 29%, rgba(255, 62, 30, 0.50) 97%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-204deg, #FF1111 29%, rgba(255, 62, 30, 0.50) 97%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-71deg, rgba(130, 254, 152, 0.50) 31%, rgba(68, 93, 204, 0.50) 92%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-71deg, rgba(130, 254, 152, 0.50) 31%, rgba(68, 93, 204, 0.50) 92%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-71deg, rgba(130, 254, 152, 0.50) 31%, rgba(68, 93, 204, 0.50) 92%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-161deg, rgba(130, 254, 152, 0.50) 31%, rgba(68, 93, 204, 0.50) 92%);
    opacity:1;
  }
  50% {
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-116deg, #F40FD1 0%, #5AD74C 95%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-116deg, #F40FD1 0%, #5AD74C 95%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-116deg, #F40FD1 0%, #5AD74C 95%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-206deg, #F40FD1 0%, #5AD74C 95%);
    background-image: -o-radial-gradient(50% 69%, rgba(137, 255, 247, 0.64) 41%, rgba(216, 209, 101, 0.50) 83%);
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 69%, rgba(137, 255, 247, 0.64) 41%, rgba(216, 209, 101, 0.50) 83%);
    background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(50% 69%, rgba(137, 255, 247, 0.64) 41%, rgba(216, 209, 101, 0.50) 83%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(50% 69%, rgba(137, 255, 247, 0.64) 41%, rgba(216, 209, 101, 0.50) 83%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-134deg, rgba(255, 0, 199, 0.50) 0%, rgba(255, 220, 30, 0.50) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-134deg, rgba(255, 0, 199, 0.50) 0%, rgba(255, 220, 30, 0.50) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-134deg, rgba(255, 0, 199, 0.50) 0%, rgba(255, 220, 30, 0.50) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-224deg, rgba(255, 0, 199, 0.50) 0%, rgba(255, 220, 30, 0.50) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-62deg, rgba(255, 245, 127, 0.50) 0%, rgba(131, 139, 176, 0.50) 96%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-62deg, rgba(255, 245, 127, 0.50) 0%, rgba(131, 139, 176, 0.50) 96%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-62deg, rgba(255, 245, 127, 0.50) 0%, rgba(131, 139, 176, 0.50) 96%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-152deg, rgba(255, 245, 127, 0.50) 0%, rgba(131, 139, 176, 0.50) 96%);
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-116deg, #1078FF 0%, #4CCCD7 95%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-116deg, #1078FF 0%, #4CCCD7 95%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-116deg, #1078FF 0%, #4CCCD7 95%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-206deg, #1078FF 0%, #4CCCD7 95%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-44deg, #FF1B1B 0%, rgba(204, 255, 99, 0.25) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-44deg, #FF1B1B 0%, rgba(204, 255, 99, 0.25) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-44deg, #FF1B1B 0%, rgba(204, 255, 99, 0.25) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-134deg, #FF1B1B 0%, rgba(204, 255, 99, 0.25) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-134deg, #F66514 0%, rgba(36, 30, 255, 0.25) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-134deg, #F66514 0%, rgba(36, 30, 255, 0.25) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-134deg, #F66514 0%, rgba(36, 30, 255, 0.25) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-224deg, #F66514 0%, rgba(36, 30, 255, 0.25) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-62deg, #1CFFB5 0%, rgba(150, 157, 188, 0.25) 96%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-62deg, #1CFFB5 0%, rgba(150, 157, 188, 0.25) 96%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-62deg, #1CFFB5 0%, rgba(150, 157, 188, 0.25) 96%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-152deg, #1CFFB5 0%, rgba(150, 157, 188, 0.25) 96%);
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-image` is not an animatable or a transitionable property and hence you cannot see it getting transitioned and it just jumps from one state to another.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) | 
[CSS Transitions Spec - Animatable CSS Properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css)

> Note that some browsers do support animations/transitions of `background-image` property but it is not standard and hence not recommended for usage. [[Source]](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/background-image)

---

You can achieve a similar effect by transitioning the `background-position` property. My understanding is that this is because `background-position` is a numeric/percentage value and hence can be transitioned as the browser can ascertain intermediate states unlike `background-image`. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/TCM9g/) for a sample.

```css
.box {
  /* Do not forget to add browser prefixes for gradients and transitions */
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-224deg, #3EAD7E 0%, rgba(29, 83, 60, 0.72) 36%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47) 50%, #1CFFB5 72%, rgba(150, 157, 188, 0.25) 96%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-224deg, #3EAD7E 0%, rgba(29, 83, 60, 0.72) 36%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47) 50%, #1CFFB5 72%, rgba(150, 157, 188, 0.25) 96%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-224deg, #3EAD7E 0%, rgba(29, 83, 60, 0.72) 36%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47) 50%, #1CFFB5 72%, rgba(150, 157, 188, 0.25) 96%);
  background: linear-gradient(-224deg, #3EAD7E 0%, rgba(29, 83, 60, 0.72) 36%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47) 50%, #1CFFB5 72%, rgba(150, 157, 188, 0.25) 96%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 0% bottom;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.box:hover {
  background-position: 100% bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Also another thing to note is that the `transition` **must** be specified in the base class and not just on `:hover`. If you specify on `hover`, it will transition while moving the mouse in but while moving out it will just jump. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/TCM9g/3/) illustrates it in comparison with the previous one.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Could you suggest another approach that I could try?

Comment: You could have a look at using `background-position` or sprites. [Mighty Meta](http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/fading-button-background-images-with-css3-transitions/) | [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fade-image-within-sprite/) | [W3Conversions](http://blog.w3conversions.com/2011/03/changing-a-background-image-with-css3-transitions/)